# I am Looking for a good Photography School / College / Course in London

Tags: service-recommendation, education, school

A friend is interested in formally studying photography, and has asked me about photo schools.  Can anyone recommend any in or near London?

I wonder if there is more information I should be supplying, so if the question is too broad, please leave a comment and I wil try to clarify.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think it's actually too localized, not too broad. Plus a little subjective. I'm not voting to close, but I'll be surprised if this gets enough response as-is to give you a meaningful survey of London-relevant opinion.

Comment: @mattdm, fair comment.  It's a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

I took classes at Zoom In in Oval, they're a charity, so in addition to your fees being pretty cheap, they spend your money on helping others : )

I started on a basic digital course with a guy called Adrian, fab tutor, and went on to do some advanced stuff, but they have a darkroom too.

The web address is: http://www.zoom-in.org

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Photography is a pretty huge field, you might want to specify what kind of school (trade, fine art, etc) you're looking to get into. A couple people I know finished [The London College of Fashion's](http://www.fashion.arts.ac.uk/courses/photography/ba_fashion_photography.htm) BS Fashion Photography program and they're pretty happy with it. One of them even works as a pro photographer, which you'll find isn't that common among people who finish photography school.